# change part of the string with case sensitive

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like the search a string without case sensitive however change  the sub string with original string's case letters.

```
var mystring = "FiRst Last";
var term = "first";  // it could be "FIRST" or fIRST

var re = new RegExp("^" + term, "i") ;
//option 1
//var t = mystring.replace(re,"<span style='font-weight:bold; color:Blue;'>" + term + "</span>");
//option 2
var t = mystring.replace(re,term.bold().fontcolor("Blue"));
```

The above code gives  **first** LAST  in blue color, however i want it to be **FiRst** LAST as mystring's case order

maybe indexof() method can be used however there might be an easy efficient way.

Comment: In other words, you need all your string uppercased, but the words matched by `term` left intact?

Comment: See this it may helpful....

[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3294576/javascript-highlight-substring-keeping-original-case-but-searching-in-case-inse][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3294576/javascript-highlight-substring-keeping-original-case-but-searching-in-case-inse

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var querystr = 'first';
var output = "FiRst Last";
var reg = new RegExp(querystr, 'gi');
var final_str = output.replace(reg, function(str) {return str.bold().fontcolor("Blue")});
```

See this following link...

[Javascript: highlight substring keeping original case but searching in case insensitive mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3294576/javascript-highlight-substring-keeping-original-case-but-searching-in-case-inse)

Solution give by user113716 may helpful...

Comment: any way to work this code with Turkish characters.   for example: querystr ='istanbul'   output = "İstanbul Turkey"

Answer (score 0):

Just use a capture group with your first option

```
var str = "FiRst Last";
var term = "first";

var t = str.replace( /(first)/i, "<span style='font-weight:bold; color:Blue;'>$1</span>");
```

t will now contain

```
"<span style='font-weight:bold; color:Blue;'>FiRst</span> Last"
```