# Highlight dropdown option programmatically in material autocomplete

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-material, autocomplete

I am using material [autocomplete](https://v15.material.angular.io/components/autocomplete/examples)(v-15). I need to highlight the dropdown(mat-select) to programmatically selected value.
For ex:

1. I want to set default item as **jhon** on click of **reset** button.
2. When I hit the button, the input field is updating(i,e jhon) but the value(jhon) is not selected or highlighted in the dropdown.

[image]

How to highlight the selected item in the mat-option ??
Pasting
[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/rh2krz-rc5ged?file=package.json,src%2Fapp%2Fautocomplete-auto-active-first-option-example.html,src%2Fapp%2Fautocomplete-auto-active-first-option-example.ts,src%2Findex.html) link

**HTML**

```
<form class="example-form" [formGroup]="customerForm">
 <mat-form-field class="example-full-width" appearance="fill">
  <mat-label>Number</mat-label>
  <input type="text" placeholder="Pick one" aria-label="Customer" 
    matInput formControlName="customer" [matAutocomplete]="auto"
   (keyup)="searchCustomers($event)"/>
   <mat-autocomplete autoActiveFirstOption #auto="matAutocomplete"
   [displayWith]="getOptionText">
    <mat-option *ngFor="let customer of filteredCustomers" 
       [value]="customer">
        {{customer.label}}
     </mat-option>
   </mat-autocomplete>
 </mat-form-field>
 <button (click)="reset()">RESET</button>
</form>
```

**TS**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder, FormControl, FormGroup, Validators} from 
 '@angular/forms';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { map, startWith } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Component({
  selector: 'autocomplete-auto-active-first-option-example',
  templateUrl: 'autocomplete-auto-active-first-option-example.html',
  styleUrls: ['autocomplete-auto-active-first-option-example.css'],
});
 export class AutocompleteAutoActiveFirstOptionExample implements 
 OnInit {
 myControl = new FormControl('');
 filteredCustomers: any = [];
 customerForm!: FormGroup;
 customers: any = [
  { label: 'peter', value: 1 },
  { label: 'jhon', value: 2 },
  { label: 'wade', value: 3 },
  { label: 'aamir', value: 4 },
  { label: 'bairstow', value: 5 },
 ];

 constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {}

ngOnInit() {
  this.customerForm = this.fb.group({
   customer: new FormControl(
     { value: '', disabled: false },
     Validators.required
   ),
 });
 this.filteredCustomers = [...this.customers];
}

 reset() {
   let defaultCustomer = { label: 'jhon', id: 2 };
   this.customerForm.get('customer')!.setValue(defaultCustomer);
  } 

 getOptionText(option: any) {
  return option.label;
 }

searchCustomers(event: any): void {
  const searchItem = event.target.value;
  this.filteredCustomers = [];
  if (searchItem.length > 0) {
    this.filteredCustomers = this.customers.filter((item: any) => {
    return item.label.toLowerCase().includes(searchItem.toLowerCase());
  });
  } else {
  this.customerForm.get('customer')?.setValue('');
   setTimeout(() => {
    this.filteredCustomers = [...this.customers];
   }, 1000);
  }
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use as array to search an object with value and text

In filter function we transform the text to highligth it like the response of @servy to this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3294576/javascript-highlight-substring-keeping-original-case-but-searching-in-case-inse)

```
  control = new FormControl('', Validators.required);
  options: any[] = [
    { value: 'One', text: '' },
    { value: 'Two', text: '' },
    { value: 'Three', text: '' },
  ];
  filteredOptions!: Observable<any[]>;

  //the function in the response of @serve to the SO
  highlight = (needle: string, haystack: string) =>
    haystack.replace(
      new RegExp(needle, 'gi'),
      (str) => `<strong>${str}</strong>`
    );

  ngOnInit() {
    this.filteredOptions = this.control.valueChanges.pipe(
      startWith(''),
      map((value) => this._filter(value || ''))
    );
  }

  private _filter(value: string): any[] {
    const filterValue = value.toLowerCase();

    return this.options
      .filter((option: any) => option.value.toLowerCase().includes(filterValue))
      .map((option: any) => {
        return {
          value: option.value,
          text: this.highlight(value, option.value),
        };
      });
  }

  //when blur, if control.value, I put the  first value of the option
  selectFirst(options: any[], control: AbstractControl) {
    if (control.value) {
      const values =
        options.filter((option: any) =>
          option.value.toLowerCase().includes(control.value)
        ) || [];
      this.control.setValue(
        values.length ? values[0].value : control.value || ``
      );
    }
  }
```

Well, we need show the "text" inside a div and use innerHTML

```
<mat-form-field appearance="outline">
  <mat-label>Fill form field</mat-label>
  <input matInput placeholder="Placeholder" [matAutocomplete]="auto" 
                  [formControl]="control" 
                  (blur)="selectFirst(options,control)"/>

  <mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete">
    @for (option of filteredOptions | async; track option) {
    <mat-option [value]="option.value">
       <div class="option" [innerHTML]="option.text"></div>
    </mat-option>
    }
  </mat-autocomplete>
  <mat-error>Email is <strong>required</strong></mat-error>
  <mat-hint>Hint</mat-hint>
</mat-form-field>
```

NOTE: I add the class "option" to our options. This allow us add a global class (e.g. in styles.css) like

```
.option strong{
  color:red;
}
```

NOTE2: if we don't want filter **NOT** use `requireSelection` else transform the function _filter removing the filter:

```
  private _filter(value: string): any[] {
    const filterValue = value.toLowerCase();

    //see how only change the "text" of the options, not filter
    return this.options
      .map((option: any) => {
        return {
          value: option.value,
          text: this.highlight(value, option.value),
        };
      });
  }
```

See [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-pipaxg?file=src%2Fmain.ts)

**Update** if the only we want is "hightligth" the whole option we can take a similar approach. In this case our array is like

```
options: any[] = [
    { value: 'One', preselect: false },
    { value: 'Two', preselect: false },
    { value: 'Three', preselect: false },
  ];
```

And the .html take account this "preselect" property

```
<mat-autocomplete  #auto="matAutocomplete" >
    @for (option of filteredOptions | async; track option) {
    <mat-option [value]="option.value">
       <div class="option" [class.hightlight]="option.preselect">{{option.value}}</div>
    </mat-option>
    }
  </mat-autocomplete>
```

Now, the function _filter give value to "preselect"

```
  private _filter(value: string): any[] {
    const filterValue = value.toLowerCase();
    const optionSelected=this.options.find(option=>option.value.toLowerCase().includes(value.toLowerCase()))
    return this.options
      .map((option: any) => {
        return {
          value: option.value,
          preselect: value && option==optionSelected,
        };
      });
  }
```

As always we can use in styles.css

```
.option.hightlight{
  color:royalblue;
}
```

Another [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-epnd4o?file=src%2Fmain.ts)